# kendoDropDownList() is not a function with requireJs

Tags: jquery, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, require

Hello I have this js file where I define the dependencies

```
define(["jquery", "core", "dropdown", "bootstrap"], function ($, kendo, kendoDropDownList, bootstrap) {
console.log(kendo);
    $("#testCont").kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: {
            data: [{ name: "Jane Doe", value: 1 }, { name: "John Doe", value: 2 }]
        },
        dataTextField: "name",
        dataValueField: "value"
    });
   }
});
```

I integrate this js file into my cshtml file with require

```
 <script>
    require(["js/Feature/feature"], function () { });
</script>
```

And, also, this is my require configuration file

```
require.config({
paths: {
    "jquery": "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min",
    "bootstrap": "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min",
    "core": "node_modules/kendo-ui/js/kendo.core.min",
    "dropdown": "node_modules/kendo-ui/js/kendo.dropdownlist.min"
 }
});
```

and I get the KendoDropDownList() is not a function. In the network from console I can see that kendo.dropdownlist.min.js is loaded but not the other dependencies that are necessary. Any ideas?

I downloaded the kendo-ui trial from telerik and i copy pasted into my node_modules folder.